# "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr" Error while creating truth tables in LaTeX

Tags: tables, overleaf, arrays

I've been trying to create my own truth table for a homework but I couldn't do it.
The code is given below.

```
\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline p & q & r & p \wedge \neg r & q \downarrow (\neg p \rightarrow r) & \neg r  \mid p & \neg q \\
\hline D & D & D & Y & ~ & ~ & Y \\
\hline D & D & Y & D & Y & ~ & Y \\
\hline D & Y & D & ~ & ~ & ~ & D \\
\hline D & Y & Y & ~ & ~ & ~ & D \\
\hline Y & D & D & Y & ~ & ~ & Y \\
\hline Y & D & Y & Y & ~ & ~ & Y \\
\hline Y & Y & D & ~ & ~ & ~ & D \\
\hline Y & Y & Y & ~ & ~ & ~ & D \\
\hline
\end{array}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be *as small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. This said, your problem is that your table has `7` columns but your table specifications `{|r|r|}` say there are only 2. Try `{|*7{r|}}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the problem was caused by number of alignment tabs specified in the `\begin{array}` command does not match the number of columns in my table.
Fixed it by rewriting it the way given below.

```
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
p & q & r & p \wedge \neg r & q \downarrow (\neg p \rightarrow r) & \neg r \mid p & \neg q \\
\hline
D & D & D & Y & \sim & \sim & Y \\
\hline
D & D & Y & D & Y & \sim & Y \\
\hline
D & Y & D & \sim & \sim & \sim & D \\
\hline
D & Y & Y & \sim & \sim & \sim & D \\
\hline
Y & D & D & Y & \sim & \sim & Y \\
\hline
Y & D & Y & Y & \sim & \sim & Y \\
\hline
Y & Y & D & \sim & \sim & \sim & D \\
\hline
Y & Y & Y & \sim & \sim & \sim & D \\
\hline
\end{array}
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you complete your code so it can be compiled?